# Insert rows from formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I need help with a task in Crystal Reports. 
In some cases I need to add several rows from formula.

For example, I have columns: Date, ParamName, ParamValue. 
If ParamValue contains several values I need to insert each one like a new row:

```
Date, ParamName, ParamValue1
Date, ParamName, ParamValue2
Date, ParamName, ParamValue3
```

In other cases leave the row as it is.
Is it possible? I can't change the initial data to solve this problem and can't find any solution for now.

Comment: Crystal Reports can't insert any new rows

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is line breaks in a displayed value, use a formula such as:

```
@{Line 1} & Chr(10) & @{Line 2} & Chr(10) & @{Line 3}
```